# Kissing spheres

Tags: blender, autocad

How to draw mutually touching/kissing spheres in Autocad, Blender or PoV-Ray...? so that the incremental spheres are in closest proximity with the first sphere drawn. Just like magnetic spheres are clumped together with maximum density and having minimum volume.

Comment: What do C++/python have to do with this?

Comment: Thats not a Programming question but a math one...

Comment: It is, blender and pov-ray are.

Comment: Are the spheres of equal radius?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on a lot of details, but if you want to do something like this, but in 3D
[image: Apollonian gasket]
then you should search for the Apollonian Gasket.

Even if you have something else in mind, it has a plenty of variations you should look into.

The 2D algorithm is available [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Apollonian_fractals) or [here for AutoCAD](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/02/circle-packing-in-autocad-creating-an-apollonian-gasket-using-f-part-1.html). And [from the same site](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/02/sphere-packing-in-autocad-creating-an-apollonian-packing-using-f-part-1.html) in 3D, again for AutoCAD.

[image: 3D packing with AutoCAD]

Comment: thanks.
The spheres will ultimately form a big sphere.
I need something like that

Comment: If you look at the [second page of last link](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2012/02/sphere-packing-in-autocad-creating-an-apollonian-packing-using-f-part-2.html) it is exactly what he is doing.